# WSO 2.5 found on server. Does this mean I''ve been hacked?

Tags: security

I found this file in my test directory. It says it's WSO 2.5, and it shows all of my files. I don't remember putting this on here, and it says it's been there since Dec 21, 2012. There's also a similar file in my public_html. Both are encrypted so it's all gibberish. Neat little interface but it looks like a hack tool.

Should I be concerned?

Comment: Apparently I can see more than my own files... I could go back into other peoples sites on the same server. What should I do about this?

Comment: I agree with Nicholas.  Weird files in odd places are a real problem if you did not create them.  Rootkit Hunter or something like it is in order.

Comment: What do I need to do to secure my site? I've renamed both files and it looks like it was contained to there.

Comment: Man people love to downvote my posts.. This is a learning site...

Comment: I apologize.. seemed like the kind of question perfect for a site that experts frequent.. now I'm downvoted so much I can't even use this site...

Comment: I believe you would have to go to http://security.stackexchange.com/ for these types of questions.  Stack overflow is normally used for programming-related questions.

Comment: More likely [webmasters.se], though I'd bet there's a similar question there already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you don't know what the output is and don't have a chron or similar job to create such output, then you might be.  There is indeed a tool called WSO, which is used for penetration testing.

If [this is the interface](http://www.invisiblehackers.in/2012/06/download-wso-new-version-25-web-shell.html) you're referring to, you most likely did get hacked.

Comment: It is indeed that interface.

Comment: Then someone was snooping around.  You need to be careful because you could end up hosting malware without even knowing.  So look at your infrastructure (web server, etc.) and see what you can do to lock it down.  Good luck.

Comment: It's a host provided server, I'll call up their tech support tomorrow and see whats going on. I've had trouble with copyright theft already from competing companies in Canada and Kansas. I'd love to find out the IP of anyone that used the server that day.

Comment: Since you're on a shared host, their support should be able to help you isolate the issue.  At the very least, they should be able to review their logs to ensure that person didn't gain access to their network.  Depending on the exploit, they might be able to narrow it down to which file is vulnerable (assuming it was because of your app).